# Creating AD Users throws Authorization_RequestDenied: "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation." exception

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am creating a C# Console Application that is reading and creating Azure AD accounts for a specific tenant.
I have added a Azure AD application and noted the AppId, AppKey (secret), TenantId, TenantName.

For this to work, we utilize the following NuGet packages :

Reading the Azure AD accounts from the domain works correctly, but creating a new Azure AD account throws an exception :
    activeDirectoryClient.Users.AddUserAsync(userToBeAdded).Wait();

"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."
"{\"odata.error\":{\"code\":\"Authorization_RequestDenied\",\"message\":{\"lang\":\"en\",\"value\":\"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.\"}}}"
   at System.Data.Services.Client.SaveResult.HandleResponse()
   at System.Data.Services.Client.BaseSaveResult.EndRequest()
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.EndSaveChanges(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.Extensions.DataServiceContextWrapper.d__74.MoveNext()

The authentication is performed by using the AppId & Secret because the Console application doesn't have UI.

```
public async Task<string> AcquireTokenAsyncForApplication()
{
AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantName, false);
// Config for OAuth client credentials 
ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential("<appid>", "<appsecret>");
var authenticationResult = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.windows.net", clientCred);
authenticationResult.Wait();            

return authenticationResult.Result.AccessToken;
}

public void Authenticate()
{
Uri servicePointUri = new Uri("https://graph.windows.net");
Uri serviceRoot = new Uri(servicePointUri, tenantId);
activeDirectoryClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(serviceRoot,
async () => await AcquireTokenAsyncForApplication());
}
```

I enabled all permittions on the application itself and delegated permittions , but the authorization exception continues to appear.   How can I find the error here? How can I solve this issue?

Best regards,
Jens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create users via Azure Graph REST using the client credential, we can config the **Directory.ReadWrite.All** permssion for the **application permission** like figure below:
[image]

After you acquire the access token, you can parse the token from [here](https://jwt.io/) and ensure that the **Directory.ReadWrite.All** is in the token before you create a user.

Comment: Thank you for the fast resonse.  The token parsing shows indeed : 
 "roles": [
    "Directory.Read.All"
  ],

However: in the Azure Portal , permission to other applications "Read and write directory data" is enabled.  

What am I missing here?

Best regards,
Jens

Comment: For that permission you might have to go through admin consent flow to approve it for the app.

Comment: Dear, how do I know this? In the Azure portal (new & old) the permission seems active. (I am logged into the portal with an Azure AD administrator)

Comment: @Fei Xue is correct.  Info on the admin_consent flow is here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview/#understanding-user-and-admin-consent.

Comment: But if you parsed the token and it contains the `Directory.ReadWrite.All` role, you should be good to go, per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-permission-scopes#Directory-ReadWrite-All-privileges-detail

Comment: This isn't a multi-tenant application.  It is a Console application that needs to add / update / delete Azure Active Directory users within a specific Tenant. The admin_consent flow is not applicable here I suppose.

@dstrockis : indeed, but it doesn't have that role yet :o

Comment: Any idea here to help me out with this issue?

Comment: @Jens, The scope above should work for creating users. Would you mind sharing the full sample you were developing? And is it helpful to test it with new Azure active directory?

Comment: Hi Fei Xue, yes I can share the full sample code.  Can I send it to you?

Comment: @Jens You can share the code via [OneDrive](https://onedrive.live.com/)  and please remove the sensitive information before you upload.

Comment: Dear @FeiXue-MSFT : is it possible to send you a private mail/notification?  I'd like to test it with the current configuration so you can view it end-to-end.

Comment: I found out that the problem occured that the admin had to consent.  There is no visible indication that certain permissions were not applied / approved yet (in the Azure Portal ).